# Redis "unknown command" error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, redis, predis

I use Redis as session storage in my website (Laravel 4.2). Sometimes I get following errors. I guess ">" char broke the setex commands.

```
production.ERROR: exception 'Predis\ServerException' with message 'ERR unknown command '>'' in 

production.ERROR: exception 'Predis\ServerException' with message 'ERR unknown command 'tml>''

production.ERROR: exception 'Predis\ServerException' with message 'ERR unknown command '</div>''
```

These errors occurs rarely on production server and I can't reproduce them. Do you have any idea why these errors occurs and how can I prevent them?

```
key: laravel:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

value: s:217:"a:4:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"xxxxxxxxxxx";s:4:"lang";s:2:"fr";s:9:"_sf2_meta";a:3:{s:1:"u";i:1461777248;s:1:"c";i:1461777248;s:1:"l";s:1:"0";}s:5:"flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}}";

exception 'Predis\ServerException' with message 'ERR unknown command 'ml>'' in vendor/predis/predis/lib/Predis/Client.php:282
```

**Update**

Code example where I am using redis.

```
    public function view($username = null)
    {
        $username = mb_strtolower($username);
        $redis = $this->getRedis();
        try{
            $view = $redis->get(User::getCacheKeyByUsername($username));
        }catch (\Exception $exception){
            $view = null;
        }
        if($view === null || Session::has("admin")){
            $user = User::where('username', '=', $username)->where("status", 1)->first();
            if (empty($user)) {
                return Redirect::to(Session::get("lang") . '/all');
            }
            $view = View::make("view", array("user" => $user));
            if(!Session::has("admin")){
                try{
                    $redis->setex(User::getCacheKeyByUsername($username), 3600, $view);
                }catch (\Exception $exception){
                    Log::error($exception->getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        return $view;
    }
```

Comment: Wrong string interpolation ?

Comment: @Ferid Movsumov, Does this problem solved?

Comment: @mnv unfortunately problem still exists.

Comment: I had same problem today. Maybe it is your case too: https://github.com/nrk/predis/issues/328

Comment: @mnv thank you for information but it is different issue

Comment: Can you show your exact code where redis is used ?

Comment: @DhruvPathak I added code example. I hope it will help.

Comment: @FeridMovsumov Just a wild guess, but did You tried to `->render()` view before passing it to redis? Just instead of `$view` try to put `$view->render()`

Comment: @GiedriusKiršys it works same as render. Because toString calls render. It stores rendered html

Comment: @FeridMovsumov Understood. Maybe workaround would be to convert special characters to html entities and then, when retrieving it, reverse process? I am talking about `htmlspecialchars` and `htmlspecialchars_decode`

Comment: I think you should `serialize($view)` or encode it some other way and unserialize/decode it when retrieving.

Comment: @GiedriusKiršys I will try this solution.

Comment: @GiedriusKiršys your solution solve my problem. Please write this as answer and I will accept it

Comment: @FeridMovsumov Ok, done. Thank You, glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so basically what can I say from Your error log: redis doesn't like special characters like `<` and `>`, so You have to encode them.

Use `htmlspecialchars` to encode and `htmlspecialchars_decode` to decode data when retrieving.

Answer (score 0):

something is wrong with your redis client. You can not reproduce it, because the error does not happen in your code, but in TCP communication between client and redis server.

i would suggest to update the question and mention what redis client module are you using. Is it predis?

If you are on unix, try compile and install phpredis. it is php module and I never had any problems with it.

---

## Reproduction with telnet

Do `telnet host port` and follow instructions:

Normal request `GET a` would look like this:

```
*2
$3
get
$1
a
$-1
```

Now consider this - ask for `gem a`:

```
*2
$3
gem
$1
a
-ERR unknown command 'gem'
```

Protocol is valid, but command "gem" is invalid.

Now consider this:

```
*1
$3
ml>
-ERR unknown command 'ml>'
```

Here is your error. Valid protocol, invalid command.

Alternatively consider this:

```
*2
$3
get
$1
<html>
$-1
-ERR unknown command 'ml>'
```

Here is your error again. Invalid `strlen("<html>");`

## Why this is redis client error and not user error:

Many redis clients uses `PHP` `magic methods`.

This means if you call `$redis->bla()`, they extract "bla" part and it parameters and forward them to the `redis` server.

However you can not do `$redis->ml>()`. This will be syntax error. So this is error from redis client, not from your code.

It also looks like part of `HTML`. It looks like you are storing `HTML` data in redis. I only can guess that the client does not compute `strlen()` or `count()` and send wrong information "down the telnet line".

Comment: thanks for -1. Once again - something is wrong with redis library. I will edit how you can reproduce the error with telnet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Nick but how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I will search this error inside predis client. I will let you know result.

Comment: install phpredis at least to check, link is  https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis - this is 100% supported in Laravel, because is de-facto standard for redis connectivity.